# Flask rendering templates from another folder

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a simple flask app with only an index.html page (so far), it's located in a folder with a bunch of javascript and CSS, which makes it a bit difficult to render.

I tried listing the file path for my HTML, however, it gives an internal server error, when I open the browser. Should I instead declare the path as a variable and pass that in?

I'm on Linux  Ubuntu 16.04 btw.

here is my sample code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('/frontend/index.html')
```

here is how my directory is listed

```
--flaskwebsite
----routes.py
----routes.pyc
----templates
------frontend(other folders, javascript files etc)
------index.html
```

Comment: You'd better separate the html templates and all static file. html files should be inside a "templates" folder and other files in a "static" folder, take a look at [this doc](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/organizing.html#organization-patterns)

Comment: You're right i have fixed that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Im seeing your folder structure correctly.

`'templates/frontend/index.html'`

Also you should have a separate template folder and a separate folder for static files such as css, js, pictures, and fonts.

Comment: Thank you. I made it work with only rendering index.html without the full path, but now it wont render the css and javascript, which folder should i place that in?

Comment: Flask automatically looks for a folder called `static` in the root of the project you're currently working on.