# Sending data directly to index.html from Flask render_template

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape data from a website. I want to display the extracted data on a separate HTML page. 
 Unfortunately, to send said data, I'm using Flask, which only allows me to send data to render_template, which as far as I understand requires your HTML files to be in a "template" folder.
I want the data to be displayed within a `<p>` element on index.html, which I don't want to be in another folder.

Here's the code that runs on main.py 
 (I'm running everything on a server)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app=Flask(__name__)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Scraping starts
url = "https://example.com" 
req = requests.get(url)
bs0bj = BeautifulSoup (req.text, "html.parser")

data=bs0bj.find_all('div', {"class": "exampleClass"})
data=data[0].text 
data=data.strip()

#Send to index.html
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html',data=data)
```

You should be able to display the received data in html with something like
`<p>{{data}}</p>`

I can't seem to find a way to send the data from main.py to index.html, and how to receive the data from main.py inside index.html
Other options that don't use Flask are also welcome.

Comment: "Flask, which only allows me to send data to render_template" -- untrue. You can just return the HTML string, or JSON, or whatever, from your route, `return f"<p>{data}</p>"`. As an aside, prefer `lxml` to `html.parser`.

Comment: What would I have to write on the HTML file to receive the data that I'm returning from Flask?

Comment: Nope, it's literally the code I gave above. HTML files are totally optional.

Comment: But my question specifically requires a separate HTML page to receive the data and to be able to use it outside of the python code. I can't seem to understand how I can do that.

Comment: If you want to pass the data to a templating engine-based HTML page like jinja2, then use it and add the `<p>{{data}}</p>` to that template. Your existing code seems fine, if that's what you want. I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: I wanted to use the data in my index.html page, which I don't want to (or can't, I think) put in a template folder.

Comment: OK, I see. Why can't you put it in the template folder? Have you seen [Flask rendering templates from another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915593/flask-rendering-templates-from-another-folder) and [Flask - How to change the directory of the templates folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68623760/flask-how-to-change-the-directory-of-the-templates-folder)?

Comment: For a general consistency in organization and also because I can't seem to display the index.html page when running the server when that page is in another folder. Edit: I'll check these links out.

Comment: Hmm. Seems like the default organization Flask uses, templates go in `templates` and static files go in `static` seems organized. What folder did you want `index.html` to be in? I sort of follow what you're having a problem with (you don't want to use a `templates` folder), but I don't really know why it has to be a problem if you don't mind using the default approach, unless there's a good reason not to, but I'm not clear what that reason would be. If all else fails, you can always read the file from anywhere, manually run the template engine and send the string. Not recommended but possible.

Comment: I tried putting my pages in the `templates` folder and the static files in the `static` folder, but now index.html doesn't display when running the server, which is what I feared would happen. I don't have the most advanced understanding of file organization in HTML, so I don't know the specifics. I'm fine with having templates and static folders but how do I display index from them. And finally, what would be that other option you suggested?

Comment: OK, that seems like the deeper problem to solve, rather than trying to work around it. Thanks for bearing with me. `@app.route('/')` should serve `index.html` from the templates directory when you navigate to the root of your site. How are you running your server and accessing the site? Are you developing on localhost?

Comment: I'm working on Adobe Dreamweaver but since it doesn't support python, I uploaded everything on repl.it because I knew I could run things from there. Everything ran fine outside of folders, the pages displayed and I could go to other pages I had hyperlinked. But the data I had from flask in the python file didn't display on index, as expected. I said server earlier but I haven't actually tried running a local server, I ran it all on repl.it.

Comment: Did you use the Flask template from repl.it? I suspect your Flask server isn't running or isn't configured correctly and you're just navigating to static HTML pages. You should be able to print something in the `/` route handler and see it print when you hit that route on the root path. If not, the config is wrong. You might want to copy files locally and run it on localhost where you can be sure of the environment.

Comment: I wasn't using the Flask template. Will do that now. Another option I was thinking was to use a javascript library equivalent to BeautifulSoup, so that I can simply run it inline with a page without going through Flask. I believe there's JSSoup for that.
Edit: I ran it with the Flask template, and after installing the dependencies and running it again, it waits a second and then stops.

Comment: Do you have a public link or can you invite me to the project? When it stops, is there an error message? The problem with a JS-only front end is that often requests are blocked cross-origin, so it depends on the site. https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere sometimes works as a proxy, but you'd have to try it on your use case. Here's an example: https://codepen.io/ggorlen/pen/qBZZxWW

Comment: I'd rather not, simply because it's already been a big enough hassle for the both of us and I think it'll be simpler to find some other way for web scraping that doesn't go outside of HTML and javascript. It'll probably be better for future things too. But I can't thank you enough for your help, and I apologize for the dead end :/
Edit: No, there's no error message, it's a blank console.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!